# Why does LogisticRegressionModel fail at scoring of libsvm data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

> Load the data that you want score. The data is stored in libsvm format
>   in the following manner: label index1:value1 index2:value2 ... (the
>   indices are one-based and in ascending order)    Here is the sample data
>   100 10:1 11:1 208:1 400:1 1830:1

```
 val unseendata: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,unseendatafileName)
    val scores_path = results_base + run_id + "/"  + "-scores"
// Load the saved model
    val lrm = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc,"logisticregressionmodels/mymodel")

    // I had saved the model after the training using save method. Here is the metadate for that model LogisticRegressionModel/mymodel/metadata/part-00000
{"class":"org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel","version":"1.0","numFeatures":176894,"numClasses":2}

      // Evaluate model on unseen data
       var valuesAndPreds = unseendata.map { point =>
       var prediction = lrm.predict(point.features)
        (point.label, prediction)
    }

// Store the scores
    valuesAndPreds.saveAsTextFile(scores_path)
```

Here is the error message that I get:

> 16/04/28 10:22:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID
>   5, ): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)  at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.predictPoint(LogisticRegression.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearModel.predict(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:76)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that throws the exception is `require(dataMatrix.size == numFeatures)`.

My **guess** is that the model was fit with `176894` features (see `"numFeatures":176894` in the output of the model) while the libsvm file has only `1830` features. The numbers must match.

Change the line where you load libsvm to be:

```
val unseendata = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, unseendatafileName, 176894)
```